Next.js - Unhandled Runtime Error, NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node
I am getting these error while login to dashboard. Once this error came and refresh the page I am getting the dashboard. If I go back to login then also this error is there.
I have two layouts. One for common and other for admin. Is that causing error?
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import LayoutProvider from "./Provider";
import NoSsr from "@/utils/NoSsr";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import OffCanvas from "@/CommonComponent/Offcanvas";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NoSsr>
          <ToastContainer />
          <LayoutProvider>
            {children}
            <OffCanvas />
          </LayoutProvider>
        </NoSsr>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

this was the common layout.js in src/app/layout.js
"use client";

import './layout.css';
import '../../../public/assets/scss/style.scss';
import Sidebar from "@/components/Admin/Layouts/Sidebar";
import Header from "@/components/Admin/Layouts/Header/index";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Layout = ({ children, className, ...rest }) => {
  const { sideBarType } = useSelector((store) => store.themeSlice);
  const backgroundColor = useSelector((store) => store.headerSlice.backGroundChange);
  const pathname = useSearchParams();
  const session = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const pageWrapper = document.getElementById("page-wrapper");
      if (pageWrapper) {
        if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
          pageWrapper.classList.remove("horizontal-wrapper");
          pageWrapper.classList.add("compact-wrapper");
        } else if (sideBarType !== "horizontal-wrapper") {
          pageWrapper.classList.remove("horizontal-wrapper");
          pageWrapper.classList.add("compact-wrapper");
        } else {
          pageWrapper.classList.add("horizontal-wrapper");
          pageWrapper.classList.remove("compact-wrapper");
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, [sideBarType]);

  return (
    <div id="mainLayout" className={`${backgroundColor}`}>
      <div className={`page-wrapper ${sideBarType} ${pathname.get("layout")}`} id="page-wrapper">
        <Header />
        <div className="page-body-wrapper horizontal-menu">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="page-body"> {children}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


this is admin layout which is in src/app/admin/layout.js
I think the layout is causing problem. I am using nextjs(Javascript).Is there any solution?

what is the error you are getting?

Page redirect to dashboard with error in screen as "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

This is happening because the the element may not be available when you are doing the removal. Please try updating the handleResize function as:
const handleResize = () => {
  const pageWrapper = document.getElementById("page-wrapper");
  if (pageWrapper) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
      if (pageWrapper.classList.contains("horizontal-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.remove("horizontal-wrapper");
      }
      if (!pageWrapper.classList.contains("compact-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.add("compact-wrapper");
      }
    } else if (sideBarType !== "horizontal-wrapper") {
      if (pageWrapper.classList.contains("horizontal-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.remove("horizontal-wrapper");
      }
      if (!pageWrapper.classList.contains("compact-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.add("compact-wrapper");
      }
    } else {
      if (!pageWrapper.classList.contains("horizontal-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.add("horizontal-wrapper");
      }
      if (pageWrapper.classList.contains("compact-wrapper")) {
        pageWrapper.classList.remove("compact-wrapper");
      }
    }
  }
};

Once this is done, debug into why the element was not present in first place.
